# How to enforce merging for hotfixes in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, merge, branching-and-merging

We are using the TFS Advanced Branch Plan:

[image: Branching Plan]

Is there a way that we can enforce that hotfixes must be merged up to the Servicing branch? We recently had an incident whereby we deploy V1.2.0 of the application, but it did not contain changes made in V1.1.1.

Or will this just have to be a manually enforced process?

Answer (score 1):

We have an automatically-scheduled script which performs such merges. The gist of it is:

```
tf merge src dest
tf resolve /auto:AutoMerge
tf checkin
```

It's too elaborate to post here, since it has much logging and monitoring - it alerts me whenever there's a merge conflict, etc.